# Prettier adding a trailing whitespace

Tags: css, prettier

I am stuck at trying to figure out how to disable prettier formatting on the following css.

It always adds a trailing space on the line

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: `rgba(${colorBlack}, 0.2)`;

becomes

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: `rgba(${colorBlack}, 0.2) `;
```

Can be reproduced in the playground prettier.io/playground

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the code as described below:

```
/* prettier-ignore */
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: `rgba(${colorBlack}, 0.2)`;
```

This will enable you to disable prettier for that particular line in the css file.

For further details on ignoring prettier in different files or lines, you can refer [link](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html).